# Adding search functionality to master/detail flow activity

Tags: android, search, master-detail

I create a master/detail activity, and added items to the master list and also info to the detail activity(using dummy content). I added a search widget(search View) to the action bar.

I have followed the tutorial on developers.android.com on how to get the search view functioning. But still to no avail I have followed different tutorials and still hv not succeeded.After creating the searchable.xml, and searchResultyActivity files, I tie them together in my manifest file but on lunching the app it says "unfortunatley app_name has stop". I think am not giving the proper declararton in my manifest file.

I need detail example with code on how to implement the search ,

1. Code for searchable.xml
2. Code for searchresultactivity.
3. Code been added to the onCreate Method of my listactivity.
4. Mostly importantly code or how to properly tie them together in my manifest file.

I am using master/detail activity